# Android : Empty SoapAction

Tags: android, android-webservice

My requirement is to call a web service from Android and display the result in a nice manner.

But inside the web service's WSDL I don't find a SOAPAction. The WSDL looks like this:

```
<wsdl:operation name="validateRef1">
  <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:input name="validateRef1">
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output name="validateRef1Response">
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to SoapAction as empty  like  String SOAP_ACTION = "";